# how to connect to local database in electron

Tags: electron, angular5

I'm new to electron and I'm writing a simple application in angular 5 and electron.i wonder how to store data in my application like personnel forms. I know its possible to store data in MySQL and other database engines in Nodejs code.But I want to store my data in a database engine like SQLite or MySQL using the angular code in typescript.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert but I solved for what I want to do with my angular5+electron:

1) I installed this package https://github.com/Inoverse/ngx-fs;

2) in CLI: `ng generate service yourServiceName`;

3) my `your-service-name.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; //default from CLI command //
import { FsService } from 'ngx-fs'; // add this line After step 1 //

@Injectable()
export class youServiceNameService {

    myDatabaseTable1: Array< any >; // you can pull all the DB in the var
    myDatabaseTable2: Array< any >; // I separated the tables
    fileSystem: any; // where I put my FS

    constructor(
        private _fsService: FsService
    ) {
        this.fileSystem = this._fsService.fs; // the property fs of
 // the _FsService contents is described here https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html
        this.readDB();
    }

    readDB() {
        this.fileSystem.readFile( 'databaseOrTable.json', ( error, data ) => {
            if ( error ) throw error;
            this.clients = JSON.parse( data );
            console.log( this.clients );
        } );

    }
}
```

4) Import your service into the component you want.

Comment: thanks for taking time and answering my question, storing data in json file fits for small data stores but if you want to store bigger data you should connect to a local database like MSSQL.I wonder if there isn't any way to connect to local SQL server so there's no need to use Electron for applications that stores data locally.